# How to return a value from Javascript callback function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, closures

This question may seem duplicate but unfortunately I couldn't understand other answers.

I'm trying to assign value from callback function to parent variable.

For example

```
let orientation = null;
orientation = Exif.getData(image, function(){
   return "somevalue";
});
```

Here how can I assign "somevalue" to orientation?

Comment: Can you shouw your getData function?

Comment: I believe `Exif.getData` is an asynchronous function, so you will have to `await` it in an `async` function to use it synchronously.

Comment: See also my blog post [JavaScript: How (not) to get a value “out of” a callback](https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it the following way:

```
let orientation = null;
Exif.getData(image, function(){
   orientation = "somevalue";
});
...
if(!orientation) //The callback probably did not run
```

Comment: I tried that but returns "True" only.

Comment: Sorry, I was set orientation = Exif.getData but now it return null with this code.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the exif-js lib. I have been testing it and the callback code does not run.